# Write a file into a the memory of the Redis server possible?

Tags: memory, redis, server

I have started to use the Redis server. And the following question comes to my mind when I work through the documentation:

If I have a file, let's say **test.txt**. Is it possible to write the content of the file into the memory of Redis?

When I type the following command: `SET file "test.txt"` , then file contains only the string "test.txt" and not the content. 
How can I achieve that? Is such an upload command existing ? If yes, which command should I type ?

I hope someone can help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

You may misunderstand how Redis works. It is primarily *key* and *value*.

But nothing stops you from *reading* your entire file into a single variable and storing that as the *value* with a given key.

Then again, maybe you rather want a document-oriented database.  I am very, very content with Redis for mostly numerical data (in size and volume).

Comment: So, if I wrote a lua script which reads the file content into a variable, then it would work? Ok, I thought a command would exist. OK, thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, you can't do that from a Lua script. Simple reason: if the Lua script is executed on another server, in a redis slave, you can't depend on the external file being present with the same contents. Solution: send the file contents as value, file name as key. Then again, reconsider if Redis is what you want/need. It might be, it might not.